# Anyone recognize [RewriteRule ^blood-sugar....] on .htaccess file?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

this is my first time posting a question here. I have been bothered by this mysterious code that occurring on the .htaccess file of my WordPress site. It will repetitively show again even though I delete it. Hopefully, anyone has an idea of what it is? Thanks!!

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^diet/(.*)$ ?diet=$1\/ [L]
RewriteRule ^max/(.*)$ ?max=$1\/ [L]
RewriteRule ^blood-sugar/(.*)$ ?blood-sugar=$1\/ [L]
```

Attached my complete .htaccss file here:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^diet/(.*)$ ?diet=$1\/ [L]
RewriteRule ^max/(.*)$ ?max=$1\/ [L]
RewriteRule ^blood-sugar/(.*)$ ?blood-sugar=$1\/ [L]
# BEGIN WpFastestCache
# Modified Time: 01-06-22 9:37:30
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} *****
# Start WPFC Exclude
# End WPFC Exclude
# Start_WPFC_Exclude_Admin_Cookie
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !wordpress_logged_in_[^\=]+\=Anthony\sBert|*|*|*|*
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !wordpress_logged_in_[^\=]+\=*
# End_WPFC_Exclude_Admin_Cookie
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ******
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(facebookexternalhit|WP_FASTEST_CACHE_CSS_VALIDATOR|Twitterbot|LinkedInBot|WhatsApp|Mediatoolkitbot)
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(WP\sFastest\sCache\sPreload(\siPhone\sMobile)?\s*Bot)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\/){2}$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/$
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !.+
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !comment_author_
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !safirmobilswitcher=mobil
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile} !^[a-z0-9\"]+ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/cache/all/$1/index.html -f [or]
    RewriteCond /home/venturedevelopme/public_html/wp-content/cache/all/$1/index.html -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*) "/wp-content/cache/all/$1/index.html" [L]
</IfModule>

<FilesMatch "index\.(html|htm)$">
    AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
    <ifModule mod_headers.c>
        FileETag None
        Header unset ETag
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
        Header set Pragma "no-cache"
        Header set Expires "Mon, 29 Oct 1923 20:30:00 GMT"
    </ifModule>
</FilesMatch>
# END WpFastestCache

# BEGIN GzipWpFastestCache
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddType x-font/woff .woff
    AddType x-font/ttf .ttf
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE x-font/ttf
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype font/ttf font/eot font/otf
</IfModule>
# END GzipWpFastestCache

# BEGIN LBCWpFastestCache
<FilesMatch "\.(webm|ogg|mp4|ico|pdf|flv|avif|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|webp|js|css|swf|x-html|css|xml|js|woff|woff2|otf|ttf|svg|eot)(\.gz)?$">
    <IfModule mod_expires.c>
        AddType application/font-woff2 .woff2
        AddType application/x-font-opentype .otf
        ExpiresActive On
        ExpiresDefault A0
        ExpiresByType video/webm A10368000
        ExpiresByType video/ogg A10368000
        ExpiresByType video/mp4 A10368000
        ExpiresByType image/avif A10368000
        ExpiresByType image/webp A10368000
        ExpiresByType image/gif A10368000
        ExpiresByType image/png A10368000
        ExpiresByType image/jpg A10368000
        ExpiresByType image/jpeg A10368000
        ExpiresByType image/ico A10368000
        ExpiresByType image/svg+xml A10368000
        ExpiresByType text/css A10368000
        ExpiresByType text/javascript A10368000
        ExpiresByType application/javascript A10368000
        ExpiresByType application/x-javascript A10368000
        ExpiresByType application/font-woff2 A10368000
        ExpiresByType application/x-font-opentype A10368000
        ExpiresByType application/x-font-truetype A10368000
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Expires "max-age=A10368000, public"
        Header unset ETag
        Header set Connection keep-alive
        FileETag None
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
# END LBCWpFastestCache



RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^diet/(.*)$ ?diet=$1\/ [L]
RewriteRule ^max/(.*)$ ?max=$1\/ [L]
RewriteRule ^blood-sugar/(.*)$ ?blood-sugar=$1\/ [L]




# BEGIN CACHE-CONTROL HEADER
<filesMatch ".(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|js|css|swf)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public"
</filesMatch>
# END CACHE-CONTROL HEADER


# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

# BEGIN cPanel-generated php ini directives, do not edit
# Manual editing of this file may result in unexpected behavior.
# To make changes to this file, use the cPanel MultiPHP INI Editor (Home >> Software >> MultiPHP INI Editor)
# For more information, read our documentation (https://go.cpanel.net/EA4ModifyINI)
<IfModule php7_module>
    php_flag display_errors Off
    php_value max_execution_time 180
    php_value max_input_time 180
    php_value max_input_vars 1000
    php_value memory_limit 512M
    php_value post_max_size 256M
    php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1440
    php_value session.save_path "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php72"
    php_value upload_max_filesize 128M
    php_flag zlib.output_compression Off
</IfModule>

<IfModule lsapi_module>
    php_flag display_errors Off
    php_value max_execution_time 180
    php_value max_input_time 180
    php_value max_input_vars 1000
    php_value memory_limit 512M
    php_value post_max_size 256M
    php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1440
    php_value session.save_path "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php72"
    php_value upload_max_filesize 128M
    php_flag zlib.output_compression Off
</IfModule>
# END cPanel-generated php ini directives, do not edit



# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php72” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php72 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

Comment: Scan your site with [GOTML](https://wordpress.org/plugins/gotmls) plugin.

Comment: If it's not something you or anyone working with you added to the .htaccess file then either a plugin is adding this (unlikely IMO) or there's a good chance that your site has been compromised (as in hacked). Scan it with a security plugin (as Muhammad suggested above), or use an online scanner like [Sucuri's Site Check](https://sitecheck.sucuri.net/) for example, or do both, to check for malware on your website. Also worth reading: [WordPress FAQs - My site was hacked](https://wordpress.org/support/article/faq-my-site-was-hacked/).

Comment: Where are these rules in relation to other directives in the `.htaccess` file? What happens when you request `/blood-sugar/something` vs `/?blood-sugar=something/`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you @MuhammadZohaib & cabrerahector for your recommendation on the plugin, I am currently scanning my site to see how it turns out. Will let you know if there are updates later today!

Comment: @MrWhite it doesn't seem to have any relations to the other directives, it just showed up individually in its own section. I didn't try requesting anything too as it looks very suspicious to me. Wish I could offer more to help you understand. Appericiated!

Comment: "it doesn't seem to have any relations to the other directives" - Yes, but the _order_ of the directives in relation to the other directives is significant. For instance, if these directives occur _after_ the WordPress code block then they are unlikely going to be doing anything.

Comment: @MrWhite It makes very much sense! As these codes always show on the very top of the .htaccess file and sometimes it appears twice. Do you mind if I send you a version of the .htaccess file that I saved see if you can find the odds? Let me know and thanks again for the help!